# function with ggplot and aes_

Tags: r, ggplot2

I just read hadley's article: http://rpubs.com/hadley/97970 Really cool!

Because of that I want to prepare some simple function. When I want to create a plot and use one more variable to distinguish all objects we generally use `color` or `fill` parameter. I always have a problem to remember that I should use `color` parameter in scatterplot and `fill` in e.g. boxplot.
Therefore, when I do not use color parameter I want to use red color default:

```
point <- function(data, x, y, color = NULL){
  if (is.null(color)){
    ggplot(data, aes_(x = substitute(x),y = substitute(y)))+
      geom_point(color = 'red')
    }
  else{
    ggplot(data, aes_(x = substitute(x),y = substitute(y),color = substitute(color)))+
      geom_point()
}
}
```

In this case, `point(mtcars, qsec, mpg)` works correctly but function with `color` parameter does not work at all - `point(mtcars, qsec, mpg, factor(cyl))`. Why?

Comment: What version of `ggplot` are you using? I don't think `aes_` is in any released version yet.

Comment: there was update of ggplot2 few days ago. Try `devtools::install_github("hadley/ggplot2")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have a problem with non-standard evaluation. When you run `is.null()` on `color`, you are evaluating the promise that's passed to the function. This then changes the behavior of calling `substitute()` on the variable. The behavior you are trying to get by using `substitute()` relies on being passed an un-evaluated promise. For example

```
foo<-function(x=NULL) {
   if(is.null(x)) {
       "NOTPASSED"
   } else {
       substitute(x)
   }
}

foo()
#[1] "NOTPASSED"
foo(ok)
# Error in foo(ok) : object 'ok' not found
```

The `is.null` sends R looking for a variable named `ok` which is not found. You want to be able to extract just the name of the variable and not the value.

In this case you are really just checking for missing parameters. it would be better to use `missing()`. Compare to

```
foo<-function(x) {
   if(missing(x)) {
       "NOTPASSED"
   } else {
       substitute(x)
   }
}

foo()
# [1] "NOTPASSED"
foo(ok)
# ok
```

The `missing()` function will not attempt to evaluate the promise. You can adapt this for your own function. It's really not specific to `ggplot`.