# ggplot function with condtional statement in RShiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have a basic data frame that has two columns: Project and Cost

Project  Cost
X        500
Y        200
Z        N/A

I want to create a function/visualization where if you choose Project Z as an input, then the output will give a simple message "Data Not Available" and if you select Project X or Y, then the output will be a basic visualization (bar chart).

This thread sort of hints at what I'm trying to do [function with ggplot and aes_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31732294/function-with-ggplot-and-aes)

My code is as follows:

````
bar_chart <- reactive({
  data %>%
    filter(Cost_Source %in% input$cost_source) %>%
    filter(Cost_Filter %in% input$cost_filter) 
})



output$new_chart <- renderPlot({
  bar_chart() %>%
    ggplot(aes(Cost_Source, Cost, fill = Cost_Filter)) +
    geom_col(width = 0.5) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::dollar) +
    labs(
      title = "Project Cost Chart",
      x = "Cost Source",
      y = "Cost"
    )```
````

Comment: In your server, try a validate() just before your plot.  Example: validate(need(!is.na(df$z), "Data Not Available"))

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the problem.

```
if(nrow(chart) > 0) then plot chart
else: data <- data.frame(x = c(1), y = c(1), text = c("Data Not Available")
ggplot(data, aes(x,y)) + geom_text(aes(label = text), size = 15)
```